# Stop nunjucks from escaping HTML

Tags: javascript, template-engine, nunjucks

I have a comments AJAX call which returns data of the posted comment, I also have @mention functionality built in, the server side is processing the @mentions and doing a `str_replace` on the mentioned users replacing their names with an a tag within the response, for example:

```
{
   data: {
      comment: "<a href=\"profile/derp\">Username</a> hey what's up"
   }
}
```

However I can't seem to find in the documentation how to allow nunjucks to print this as actual HTML, it escapes it and displays the code instead of letting it be a real a tag.

Does anyone know how I can allow this to be printed as an actual a tag?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

OK so almost immediately after I posted this I found the answer! for anyone else looking it's simply this; within your template where you're printing your variable add the safe filter, which will disable automatic escaping.

```
{{ comment.content|safe }}
```

Although this means it's vulnerable to [XSS injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), so make sure you add your protection on the server side.

Comment: This threw me because when I initially saw the filter, I thought it was the *opposite*--that safe would escape HTML.

Comment: you saved me :)

Answer (score 11):

You can also avoid escaping globally using:

```
nunjucks.configure({ autoescape: false });
```

Comment: Though you almost never want to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider passing the comment's meta data and letting the template create the HTML:

```
<p>
  <a href="{{ comment.user.url }}">{{ comment.user.name }}</a> {{ comment.text }}
</p>
```

Then pass the following meta data:

```
comment: {
  user: { url: "profile/derp", name: "Username" },
  text: "hey what's up"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the issue is the template does not know before hand if there will be a link, as this link is only added if there are mentions, which can be within a comment for example.

Comment: @AndréFigueira you can add a conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the devs do not change, without oversight, what's in the configuration files and accidentally introduce insecurities like XSS injections, consider adding a content security policy header to the server response. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

A Content Security Policy (CSP) is a set of policies or instructions that the browser enforces on web pages. The server sets the CSP HTTP header in its response back to a browser. During the process of loading a page, the browser has to request and render a bunch of content and code. This process is standard and usually harmless, as pretty much all modern websites are in nature complex and composed of lots of lines of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and other resources like images and files that the code references. This referenced code could be from the same origin (requested domain) or another origin; browsers usually don't distinguish that. So naturally, the browser will process and execute these resources. It is crucial that the browser does not run any malicious code or access data that does not belong to the current website.

A basic Content Security Policy header would look something like this:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self';
```

Each section in the header is pertinent to a specific kind of source. These may be images (img-src), scripts (script-src), styles (style-src), and so forth. In addition, the 'self' directive states that only resources from the same origin will be allowed to be executed. You can specify domains that you want to retrieve resources from by putting their URLs next to 'self.'

Load the response and use the browser dev tools console function to view any policy violations.

Given the above header may break the functionality of web sites, the CSP header can be set to report only (set the header to Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only) in which case the web site will be have normally, but the console will still indication areas the CSP would have had issue with the repsonse content.

You can then confirm that the resources that the alert reports are, in fact, legitimate and necessary for the proper functioning of the application. If they are, then allow them in the policy. Consider using SHA256 hashes to signature check whatever is being included to ensure it has not been tampered with.

Also consider using DOMPurify which sanitises HTML and prevents XSS attacks. You can feed DOMPurify with a string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string (unless configured otherwise) of clean HTML. DOMPurify will strip out everything that contains dangerous HTML and thereby prevent XSS attacks and other nastiness.  https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify